# Excel VBA Screenupdating False Infinite Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that maps data from one sheet (where it has been copied) to another which is then used for further analysis. When I run the code with screen updating on it always works fine. When I turn screen updating off the code gets stuck in an infinite loop in the last part of the sub (highlighted in bold - it is the inner most loop of the final section of code). If you then debug the code and re-start it continues normally and finished the code. If left it will never end, but next time will work fine:

```
Sub simsMap()

Dim simsCol As String
Dim mapCol As String

range("A5:OP253").ClearContents
range("S1:OP1").ClearContents
range("S4:OP4").ClearContents

simsCol = range("A1")
For x = 2 To 250
    If Worksheets("simsData").range(simsCol & x) <> "" Then range("A" & x + 3).Value = Worksheets("simsData").range(simsCol & x)
Next x

simsCol = range("B1")
For x = 2 To 250
    If range("A" & x + 3) <> "" Then
        If Worksheets("simsData").range(simsCol & x) = range("B2") Or Worksheets("simsData").range(simsCol & x) = range("B3") Then
            range(simsCol & x + 3) = "Y"
        Else
            range(simsCol & x + 3) = "N"
        End If
    End If
Next x

Dim simsArray As Variant
Dim mapArray As Variant
simsArray = Array("C1", "D1", "G1")
mapArray = Array("C", "D", "G")

For y = 0 To UBound(simsArray)
    simsCol = range(simsArray(y))
    mapCol = mapArray(y)
    For x = 2 To 250
        If range("A" & x + 3) <> "" Then
            If Worksheets("simsData").range(simsCol & x) = "Y" Then
                range(mapCol & x + 3) = "Y"
            Else
                range(mapCol & x + 3) = "N"
            End If
        End If
    Next x
Next y

simsArray = Array("E1", "F1", "H1", "I1", "J1", "K1", "L1", "M1", "N1", "O1", "P1", "Q1")
mapArray = Array("E", "F", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q")

For y = 0 To UBound(simsArray)
    simsCol = range(simsArray(y))
    mapCol = mapArray(y)
    For x = 2 To 250
        If range("A" & x + 3) <> "" Then
            range(mapCol & x + 3) = Worksheets("simsData").range(simsCol & x)
        End If
    Next x
Next y

Dim realColumn As String
Dim valueColumn As String
Dim columnNumber As Long
Dim realCell As String
Dim valueCell As String
Dim subjectJump As Integer

realColumn = "S"
subjectJump = 8 - Worksheets("menu").range("F17")
For y = 1 To 48
    If Worksheets("menu").range("F19") = "Y" Then
        valueColumn = range(realColumn & 1)
        realCell = realColumn & 1
        realColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(realCell).Column + 1).Address, "$")(1)
        range(realColumn & 1) = valueColumn
        For x = 1 To Worksheets("menu").range("F17")
            valueCell = range(realColumn & 1) & 1
            If range(realColumn & 1) <> "" Then valueColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(valueCell).Column + 1).Address, "$")(1)
            realCell = realColumn & 1
            realColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(realCell).Column + 1).Address, "$")(1)
            range(realColumn & 1) = valueColumn
        Next x
    Else
        If range(realColumn & 1) = "" Then
            realCell = realColumn & 1
            realColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(realCell).Column + 8).Address, "$")(1)
        Else
            For x = 1 To Worksheets("menu").range("F17")
                valueCell = range(realColumn & 1) & 1
                valueColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(valueCell).Column + 1).Address, "$")(1)
                realCell = realColumn & 1
                realColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(realCell).Column + 1).Address, "$")(1)
                range(realColumn & 1) = valueColumn
            Next x
            realCell = realColumn & 1
            realColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(realCell).Column + subjectJump).Address, "$")(1)
        End If
    End If
Next y


realColumn = "S"
For y = 1 To 384
    simsCol = range(realColumn & 1)
    mapCol = realColumn
    If range(mapCol & 1) <> "" Then
        If range("A" & 4) <> "" Then
            range(mapCol & 4) = Worksheets("simsData").range(simsCol & 1)
        End If
    End If
    realColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(realColumn & 1).Column + 1).Address, "$")(1)
Next y

realColumn = "S"
For y = 1 To 384
    simsCol = range(realColumn & 1)
    mapCol = realColumn
    If range(mapCol & 1) <> "" Then
        For x = 2 To 250
            **If range("A" & x + 3) <> "" Then
                range(mapCol & x + 3) = Left(Worksheets("simsData").range(simsCol & x), 1)
            End If**
        Next x
    End If
    realColumn = Split(Cells(1, range(realColumn & 1).Column + 1).Address, "$")(1)
    If y = 384 Then loopCheck = False
Next y

For x = 5 To 253
    If range("A" & x) <> "" Then studentNumber = x
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: use debug.print in your code and find what causes the problem, screen updating should not have any impact if your code is running fine with it turned on

Comment: thank you - was able to see the problem. code was running fine, just much slower (5 minutes vs 30 seconds). updating now to write to variant arrays and then load into the workbook.

Comment: you can upvote the good answers or tips to help other readers in the future to pick up the solutions faster. that gives credits to people who write the tips too I guess.

Comment: seems like you could put the two `For y = 1 To 384` loops into one